# Bad request in discord oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord

I'm creating a Discord login, but when I get redirected, I get the error. The error happens after I press authorize on the Discord OAuth page
`{"status":"ERROR","error":"Response code 400 (Bad Request)"}`
Here is my code for Discord.js

```js
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const fetch = require('got');
const btoa = require('btoa');
const { catchAsync } = require('../utils');

const CLIENT_ID = '#';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '#';
const redirect = encodeURIComponent('https://ezapplications.live/api/discord/callback');

router.get('/callback', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.code) throw new Error('NoCodeProvided');
const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=identify&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${redirect}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: "https://ezapplications.live/api/discord/callback",
    code: req.query.code
  })
});
  const json = await response.json();
  res.redirect(`/?token=${json.access_token}`);
}));

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=identify&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${redirect}`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my code for Server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
app.use('/api/discord', require('./api/discord'));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  switch (err.message) {
    case 'NoCodeProvided':
      return res.status(400).send({
        status: 'ERROR',
        error: err.message,
      });
    default:
      return res.status(500).send({
        status: 'ERROR',
        error: err.message,
      });
  }
});

app.listen(50451, () => {
  console.info('Running on port 50451');
});
```

Here is the code for utils.js

```js
// async/await error catcher
const catchAsyncErrors = fn => (
  (req, res, next) => {
    const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);
    if (routePromise.catch) {
      routePromise.catch(err => next(err));
    }
  }
);

exports.catchAsync = catchAsyncErrors;
```

I'm not sure why I get this error as everything seems fine to me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Authorization Code Grant](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant) docs, you need to pass the parameters in the request body instead of the query string.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: "https://ezapplications.live/api/discord/callback",
    code: req.query.code
  }).toString()
});
```

Regarding HTTP Basic auth...

> You can also pass your `client_id` and `client_secret` as basic authentication with `client_id` as the username and `client_secret` as the password

...but I don't really see the point. Your choice

Comment: Now i get the error
{"status":"ERROR","error":"The `body` option must be a stream.Readable, string or Buffer"}

Comment: I updated the original code in the question to show you what I put

Comment: Which implementation of `fetch` are you using? I've update my answer to be more explicit with the `fetch` arguments (note the `headers` and `toString()`)

Comment: @Bobjoe12 if you're using `node-fetch`, you shouldn't have had any issue with my original code. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#user-content-post-with-form-parameters

Comment: I am using got. When I use nodefetch, I get an error about es and how require doesn't work with it. I updated my code with .toString and headers, but now I get the error
{"status":"ERROR","error":"Response code 401 (Unauthorized)"}

Comment: @Bobjoe12 could you please update your question code again? FYI, you seem to be using the wrong URL in your last update

Comment: @Bobjoe12 if you're using `got`, why does your code use `fetch`?

Comment: Im using got, but the variable is called fetch

Comment: All fixed now @Phil. All i had to do was change the fetch link into the one u send me. Thank you so much!